# AWS SESv2 CLI: sending email to contacts subscribed to topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

I have created a contact list and am trying to use AWS SESv2 CLI to send an email to all contacts in the list that are subscribed to the "Announcements" topic:

```bash
aws sesv2 send-email \
    --from-email-address no-reply@mysite.xyz \
    --content '{"Template": {"TemplateName": "mytemplate"}}' \
    --list-management-options '{"ContactListName": "mylist", "TopicName": "Announcements"}'
```

I get the error:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the SendEmail operation: Destination cannot be empty
```

The [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sesv2/send-email.html) lists the `[--destination]` option in the command's synopsis as optional (that's my understanding of the square brackets). So, I thought the intention was that if destination is omitted, then the contact list in the list management options would be used instead.

What am I missing? How do I send an email to all contacts in the list that are subscribed to a particular topic?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I think `--list-management-options` doesn't mean it replaces the `destination`. `..list...which an email belongs, which will be used when a contact chooses to unsubscribe.` I think it's  like `unsubscribe` option we see in those ads email. The `destination` email will be match to the list it belongs to.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's how it works there's not much example on how it works. But `destination` is definitely a required parameter.